# Simple SELECT query problem

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have this MySql select query which seems to have a bug but I am quite "green" so I simply cannot see, so maybe you could help?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT node_id 
  FROM rate 
 WHERE node_id='".$cat_node_id_string."' 
 LIMIT ".$node_count_star.",".$node_count_end."    
 ORDER BY SUM(amount) 
 GROUP BY node_id
```

Thanks for help in advance...

UPDATE: 
I will post a mysql error to make it clearer...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY
>   node_id LIMIT 1,20' at line 5

Comment: Notice that the first parameter of limit indicates where the result will begin and the second one how many results from there on will be shown. So 5,10 will not show 5 results but 10 (starting from the 5th result row).

Comment: What exactly would you expect this to return? Since you limit the result to one `node_id`, the `GROUP BY` will only return a single line, so the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT` are pointless. However, the sequence should be `SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE .. GROUP BY .. ORDER BY .. LIMIT`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT node_id 
  FROM rate 
 WHERE node_id='".$cat_node_id_string."' 
 ORDER BY SUM(amount) 
 GROUP BY node_id
 LIMIT ".$node_count_star.",".$node_count_end."
```

Be aware though, that the result will be a single record containing whatever `$cat_node_id_string` resolves to!

- With `WHERE node_id='".$cat_node_id_string."'` you tell MySQL to only return those records where node_id matches an exact string.
- With `GROUP BY node_id` you tell MySQL to group all records into one

Answer (score 0):

Your error:
    GROUP BY node_id LIMIT ,'

That comma there suggests that your limit variables $node_count_star and $node_count_end are empty.

Cheers & good luck.